# How to make sure user type="admin" can only access a certain webpage? php mysql

Tags: php, session, authentication, admin

How do I make sure that only users with type="admin" can access for example admin.php

for example. I am logged out. but i can still access the admin.php, how to I make sure i can only access the page when i am logged in as an admin?

```
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //remove this line ******header("location:customer_home.php");
        if($row['type'] == 'admin'){
            header("location: admin.php");
        } else if($row['type'] == 'customer'){
            header("location: customer_home.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: This question is too broad to answer.

Comment: what is the problem do you have now?

Comment: Well nate's answer does explain it. Very easy example though.

Comment: I fixed my problem but it says that Unidentified Index: isAdmin how do i fix it? @Daan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is

```
if($row['type'] == 'admin'){
    $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = true;
        header("location: admin.php");
    }
```

And the on your admin.php file:

```
if($_SESSION['isAdmin']==true){

    print 'hi admin!';

}
```

However this is a 'basic' version, and I would suggest looking up PHP security, and looking up the users logged in ID with a table within your database to properly check the users logged in credentials.

Comment: Okay, that worked thank you, but how do I, redirect it with error handling? sorry for my english. :(

I get this isAdmin is and Unidentified index when placed after session_start();